# Android XML: разметка приложений

Tags: xml, android

Подскажите плиз источник про разметку для приложений для Android (интересует конкретно таблица).

Comment: Вас интересует таблица или табличный лэйаут?

Comment: простая таблица с colspan и rowspan(в html всмысле)...

Comment: Всё равно не понятно. Вы хотите расположить заранее известное количество элементов или вам нужна именно таблица с данными?

Comment: таблица с данными, расписание пар в частности

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTFM [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html)!, а если лень то возьмите любой IDE с нормальной поддержкой Android: Eclipse или Intellij IDEA, создайте `<TableLayout>` IDE вам начнет подсказывать все теги и атрибуты.